# How to re-size an input-group-addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have some input options as below, I was trying to make all of them with the same widths.

[image]

I have tried to inherit the default style by an external css as:

```
.addon
{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="well">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Field </span>
                                        <select type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="final_data.info"
                                                ng-options="m.id as m.title for m in chartlist"
                                                required ng-cloak></select>
                                    </div><br>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Function </span>
                                        <select type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="final_data.info"
                                                ng-options="m.id as m.title for m in chartlist"
                                                required ng-cloak></select>
                                    </div><br>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Lookup </span>
                                        <select type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="final_data.info"
                                                ng-options="m.id as m.title for m in chartlist"
                                                required ng-cloak></select>
                                    </div><br>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">Keyword </span>
                                        <input type="input" class="form-control" placeholder="Field" ng-model="final_data.table_name">
                                    </div><br>
</div>
```

But it re-sizes the entire input options instead of the input field's header. Can anyone suggest me a way to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not easy to help you without more code. Maybe you could add a fiddle...

Comment: Or add at least your html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be more specific with your CSS selector
Try this :

```
.input-group-addon {
    min-width:100px; // You can adapt this 
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

i create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amirtgm/t4aLmnrj/) for your problem 
and this is a css snippet!

```
.well{
  margin-left:20px;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:300px;
  height:auto;
}
.well .input-group{
  width:100%;
  clear:both;
}
.well .input-group .input-group-addon{
  background-color:#ccc;
  padding:5px;
  width:20%;
  float:left;
}
.well .input-group input,.well .input-group select {
    width: 72%;
    float: left;
    background-color: transparent;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;

}
```

make sure label tag is topper than input